# Type mismatch errors comparing cell values

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I would like to compare two cells in the same worksheet, both the results of functions/calculations with the cells in corresponding columns. I get a type mismatch error just as I ask for the cell values to be compared. Are you able to help?

```
Sub CorrAct()  
Dim x As Workbook  
Dim y As Workbook  
Dim Rng As Range  
Dim QA As Worksheet  
Dim Corr_Act As Worksheet  
Dim Expected As Range  
Dim Data As Range  

On Error GoTo 0

'## Open both workbooks first:  
Set x = ThisWorkbook  
Set y = Workbooks.Open("file:///###")   

Set QA = x.Sheets("QA ab SAB-100 ####")
Set Corr_Act = y.Sheets("Corrective Actions Register")

Set Expected = QA.Range("V10")
Set Data = QA.Range(QA.Range("F10"), QA.Range("F10").End(xlDown))


'Compare data to expected values  
For Each cell In Data.Cells
If Data.Value > Expected.Value Then    <<<ERROR HERE


'Now, transfer values from x to y:  
Corr_Act.Range("A4").Value = QA.Range("A1")

End If

Next cell  
End Sub
```

Comment: `Data.Value` should probably be `cell.Value`.  (`Data` is your column of information, `cell` is the particular cell you are looking at during that iteration of `For Each cell In Data.Cells`.)

Comment: Is `Expected` meant to be the cell from column V in the same row as `cell` (i.e. should it be `cell.Offset(0, 16)`), or is that **always** meant to be the specific cell V10?